# Whats the valve clearance measurements for a 2006 Honda fit 1.3L I-DSI (L31A) engine?

Tags: honda, valve, fit, measurement

I'm planning on adjusting the valve clearances myself for the first time but i don't know the measurements for the intake and exhaust valves clearances since its a second hand car and the manual is gone. can any of you guys please tell me?

i tried google but the answers vary so i need a pros answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you'll find the needed specs here:

[Service Specifications](http://www.hondafitjazz.com/manual/A00/HTML/00/SAA2E00000000000000NDAT01.HTML)

```
    Clearance (cold)    Intake      0.15-0.19 mm (0.006-0.007 in.)
                        Exhaust     0.26-0.30 mm (0.010-0.012 in.)
```